# Foley Metal Footsteps

Tags: foley, footsteps

Just rejoined as couldn't figure out how to get my old account back, hope your all doing well!

So on to the question, I've been trying to get metal surface footsteps to sound right for years but still not happy.... so am looking for suggestions!

I've tried a huge piece of metal (kind they put over holes in the road) - sounds to hollow.
I've tried adding a ring with a metal megaphone. Worked to an extent but the megaphone lost its mojo, and would sound like someone banging a metal bin!
I've tried adding a ring with a water cooler bottle. It's good, but it's not right....
I've tried lots of different things!! But still not how I want them to sound....

What I want them to sound like, is how they sound on the spaceship in Prometheus.... So.... any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use the [Contact Us](http://sound.stackexchange.com/contact) page and they should be able to help get your old account back.

Answer (score 1):

I have quite a large collection of different metal sheets of different thickness and size. I found that a lot of the time it is also what footwear is being worn will determine texture. Maybe experiment with hard soled shoes verses soft soled. Also, I sometimes place another piece of metal against the surface I am walking on to get an interesting resonance that increases the size and texture of the surface.

Surfaces that you may wish to consider are a metal scaffold surface (quite long but narrow with a hollow area underneath), a stripped car door- only the shell is left nothing inside; a large piece of heavy metal about a centimeter thick, grates, girders etc. I always follow the rule that get whatever you can, you never know and then PLAY!!!!!!!

Good luck

Comment: I have a stripped car door, but it tends to bend under pressure. Has to be solid. I think grates are the way forward!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a thin piece of metal will make more resonant sound than a dense large piece. You might want to try some solid metal against solid metal. Thin sheets will resonate a bit too much. Not sure where you'd get them, just throwing it out there.

The other thing to consider, if you're talking about a mech or something that is "well made", you're not going to want a lot of resonant clanking. Things that are well made and futuristic (in my opinion) would usually be made of fairly dense, solid material.

I don't think it's the answer, but i hope it at least helps you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to go back and watch Prometheus again to hear exactly what sound you mean but a lot of the time when characters are walking on a metal surface in films it's a grate or really hard mesh style sheeting. ie. It's not flexible, and it's made up in a grid formation, full of holes you could say. This gives a unique sound rather than a solid sheet of metal which is very resonant.

Short of getting some of this material and suspending it like a walkway to do your foley on, you could try using a metal ladder, laying it down and walking up and down it. With the right pitching effects on the right ladder this could work pretty well.

Another thought is to try mixing in the sound of two metal tools banging together, two wrenches for example,  with the sound of footsteps on a hard surface.

Comment: I'm thinking the grate could be the right sound; like on a suspended walkway or metal staircase. Your right about the solid sheet of metal - its way too resonant! Now just got to find me a piece of floor.